# Stumped: ExcelVBA RowSource for a ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm stumped.  I've read every thread regarding applying a RowSource to a ComboBox and just cannot get the solutions (which are mostly the same) to work.

The details are:
Excel 2010
UserForm = UFToTakeList
ComboBox = cbLvl2Selector

For which I want to have the RowSource as NRM1Lookup!NRM1GroupNoRange

I have typed:  UFToTakeList.cbLvl2Selector.RowSource = NRM1Lookup!NRM1GroupNoRange to no success.  I have added "" and '', I have tried other variations on the theme.

I can type the RowSource in the Properties box but I want to be able to concatenate another Range and know that I can apply this method to all my ComboBoxes.

I think my fundamental problem is knowing where to put the code.  It automatically selects the _Change parameter for the ComboBox within the UserForm.  If that is correct then I cannot workout why I can type the path above into the Properties box but it won't work as code.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.  My grey matter is frying.

Comment: SOLVED:  This question was asked when I was new to Excel VBA and that particular spreadsheet is no longer in use.  I didn't understand arrays back then so @Harun24HR answer made no sense to me.  I have learned a lot since 2015.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I could not understand what you want? You can try following codes, is it helpful to you or not?

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim rng As Variant

        rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        If IsArray(rng) Then
            ComboBox1.List = rng
        Else
            ComboBox1.AddItem rng
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  To clarify, I want to be able to control the RowSource of a combobox using VBA rather than type the link directly into the RowSource line of the Property box.  I have four combos boxes that are each dependent on the preceding result and will use dynamic tables to provide the source.  Yet, I cannot get the examples I've seen to work.  I will try yours in the next couple of days and see what happens.  Many thanks